# C prog error: expected expression before int

Tags: c, compiler-errors

This is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define round(a) ((a-0.5)<int(a))?int(a):int(a+1)
int main() {
double a = 5.2;
int m = round(a);
printf("%d", m); }
```

and it shows the error:  expected expression before 'int'

Comment: `(int)(a)`, not `int(a)`

Comment: It is also nice to put `return 0;` at the end.

Comment: @TheDubleM: Yes. Even nicer is to `#include <stdlib.h>` and use `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`, which is clearer than "`0`".

Answer (score 2):

`round` is a name reserved by the standard C library so it is undefined behaviour to call your macro that name (even if you don't include `math.h`).

Your algorithm could be better expressed like this:

```
#define my_round(a)  ( (int)((a) + 0.5) )
```

which also has the benefit of only evaluating its argument once.

It would be preferable to use an inline function:

```
inline int my_round(double d)
{
    return d + 0.5;    
}
```

Note that both options cause undefined behaviour if `a` is outside the bounds of `INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX` roughly . If it's in a critical environment you should make your inline function check the bounds of `d` before doing the conversion to int.

Comment: The original macro in the question produces the wrong result (for the specification implicit in the name “round”) for even floating-point numbers between 2^52 and 2^53. Your version produces the wrong result for odd floating-point numbers between 2^52 and 2^53, and also for the predecessor of 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of `int(a)`. [Syntactically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17930267/2455888) it is wrong. It should be `(int)(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
#define round(a) ((a-0.5)<int(a))?int(a):int(a+1)
```

Has the brackets in the wron places

Should be

```
#define round(a) (((int)((a)-0.5))<(a))?(int)(a):(int)(a+1)
```

Comment: You need to cast `(a)` in the comparison, otherwise it will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `int(a)` is not valid C.

Redefine your macro as follows:

```
#define round(a) (((a)-0.5)<(int)(a))?(int)(a):(int)(a+1)
```

Note that I've also added parentheses around `a` in `(a)-0.5`.

P.S. What's the reason for making it a macro and not, say, a function?