# C++ lambda syntax

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a function that searches a vector of iterators and returns the iterator if its names matches a string passed as an argument.

```
koalaGraph::PVertex lookUpByName(std::string Name, std::vector<koalaGraph::PVertex>& Vertices) {

    for (size_t i = 0; i < Vertices.size(); i++) {

        if(Vertices[i]->info.name == Name) 
            return Vertices[i];
    }
}
```

My question is how can I implement this as a lambda, to use it in connection with `std::find_if`?

I'm trying this:

```
std::vector<koalaGraph::PVertex> V;
std::string Name;
std::find_if(V.begin(), V.end(), [&Name]() {return Name == V->info.name;})
```

But it says that `V`

> an enclosing-function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list.

Comment: No `return` if nothing found?

Answer (score 22):

`find_if` is going to pass the elements of the vector into your lambda.  That means you need

```
std::find_if(V.begin(), V.end(), [&Name](auto const& V) {return Name == V->info.name;})
```

so that the `V` in the lambda body is the element of the vector, not the vector itself.

---

Ideally you'd give it a different name than `V` so you keep the vector and local variables separate like

```
std::find_if(V.begin(), V.end(), [&Name](auto const& element) {return Name == elememt->info.name;})
```

So now it is clear you are working on a element of the vector, instead of the vector itself.

Answer (score 8):

First, `V->info.name` is ill formed, inside or outside of the lambda.

The function object sent to the algoritm `std::find_if` must be a unary function. It must take the current element to check as a parameter.

```
auto found = std::find_if(
    V.begin(), V.end(), 
    [&Name](koalaGraph::PVertex const& item_to_check) {
        return Name == item_to_check->info.name;
    }
);
```

The type of `found` is an iterator to the element that has been found. If none is found, then it returns `V.end()`

If you use C++14 or better, you can even use generic lambdas:

```
auto found = std::find_if(
    V.begin(), V.end(), 
    [&Name](auto const& item_to_check) {
        return Name == item_to_check->info.name;
    }
);
```

Comment: `V->info.name` is valid syntax. It just won't typecheck since vectors don't overload `->`.

Comment: `It just won't typecheck since vectors don't overload ->` so... it won't compile? It's an invalid syntax to use `->` on object of types that don't overload `operator->`

Comment: Not all compile errors are syntax errors. See [syntax vs. semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930267/what-is-the-difference-between-syntax-and-semantics-of-programming-languages).

Comment: @SilvioMayolo The answer you linked me says that semantics is the meaning of the program, usually in it's runtime behaviour. The code I quoted is simply ill formed, there is no semantic yet. Or maybe I don't understand the concept correctly

Answer (score 4):

`std::find_if`'s predicate will receive a reference to each element of the range in turn. You need:

```
std::find_if(
    V.begin(), V.end(),
    [&Name](koalaGraph::PVertex const &v) { return Name == v->info.name; }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Get `V` as parameter to the lambda.

`std::find_if(V.begin(), V.end(), [&Name](type& V) {return Name == V->info.name;)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `const auto &` to access the individual elements from your vector in the lambda expression. Since the vector is an lvalue, auto will be deduced to `const vector<PVertex> &`. Then, you can use `std::distance` to find the element location of the object in the vector.

```
struct PVertex
{
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<PVertex> V = {{"foo"},{"bar"},{"cat"},{"dog"}};

    std::string Name = "cat";

    auto found = std::find_if(std::begin(V), std::end(V), [&Name](const auto &v){return (Name == v.name);});

    std::cout<< "found at: V["<<std::distance(std::begin(V),found)<<"]" <<std::endl;
}
```

Result is:

```
found at: V[2]
```

Example: https://rextester.com/IYNA58046