# What does "semantics" mean? and why are "move semantics" named as such, instead of any other term?

Tags: c++, semantics

In Cpp, the "move semantics" of an object refers to the concept that "move but not copy the object to a newer", but the word "semantics" really confuse me.

What is the difference between the "semantics" and "function"?
How to use this word correctly?
If I realize a method called "max(A,B)", could we say "I realize a max semantic"?
If I coding a object called "list", could we say "I realize a sequence storage semantic"?

Comment: Semantics means "meaning". The point of "move semantics" is not what it does, but what it means.

Comment: In programming languages semantics is usually opposed to syntax. Syntax describes which sequences of characters are considered to be correct in other words belong to the language. Semantics describes what these "correct" sequences of characters mean.

Comment: The _What does "semantics" mean_ part is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3355349/212858) IMO. I'm not voting to close because it doesn't cover move semantics, but you should have been able to find out what "semantics" means in general with no trouble.

Comment: @Useless thank you for your suggestions. It is strange that I had been failed to find what your referred before I asked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Semantics" is the *meaning* or interpretation of written instructions. It is often contrasted to "syntax", which describes the *form* of the instructions. For example, an assignment `foo = bar` has the same form in many programming languages, but not necessarily the same meaning. In C++ it can mean copy, in Rust it can mean move, and in Java or Python it means copy the object reference.

"Move semantics" applied to C++ constructs such as assignment or argument passing is the situation in which the syntax of those constructs is interpreted as object move as opposed to object copy. Semantics is not a synonym for "function", so "`max` semantics" doesn't make much sense.

Other examples where the word can be applied is [reference semantics](https://hackingcpp.com/cs/value_vs_reference_semantics.html) as opposed to value semantics, or "short-circuit semantics" (of the `&&` and `||` operators) as opposed to eager evaluation. Basically, anything where there are multiple possible meanings of what you wrote, and you need to name and pinpoint the correct one.